# Installed application not opening mysql database embedded with

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, windows-services, c#-3.0

I made a setup for my Windows application which contains two projects one is a windows service which is used to load the database (Server /Client).And one project is for front end for the application which uses the database loaded from it . It is working fine in development environment. ( I am using .net Framework 3.5,Visual Studio 2008 SP1).
But when I created a setup for it it and run the application . It is not connecting the database. Dose any body have any solutions or suggestions. If so please help me ...........!!!

Comment: how connection string is stored? in app.config?? verify the app.config for valid connection string.

Comment: It is stored in .ini file in service application, And i have added a mysql class from service application as link to my FrontEnd application. Ud using this class I am calling the database ..

Comment: check whether it is able to read ini file and read the correct db conncetion string

Comment: Its working fine in development environment. I have problem only when istalling the setup and access the application ....!!!

Comment: you have add some logs when loading connection string and while creating connection and see.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37530/discussion-between-neo-and-rajesh-subramanian)

Answer (score 1):

Try installing MySql Connector, that may solve some database issues for windows applications in some occasions.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using appconfig connection string give like this " Dim conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("Server=" & server & ";Database=" & Database & "; uid=" & uid & "; pwd=" & pwd & ";")"
i hope this is work for you.